# `xcalib -i -a` won't invert colors anymore

Tags: 20.04, radeon, colors, xcalib

I used to use the `xcalib -i -a` command on my old desktop system running 18.04 with an onboard Intel graphics card. This `xcalib -i -a` command successfully inverted my system colors.

I just got a fancy new 20.04 desktop with a Radeon graphics card and now when I issue the `xcalib -i -a` command the screen output is just garbled. I can barely make out the terminal and I issue the `xcalib -i -a` command again to make my screen go "back to normal".

Why doesn't `xcalib -i -a` work anymore, and is there any other way to quickly invert Ubuntu 20.04 screen colors?

I'm running a default session which I believe is X11 and NOT Wayland. So not sure why I'm having issues. And `xrandr --output VGA-0 --brightness -1` does not work, and garbles my screen output the same as described above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The extension "Invert Color" might work for you as a quick-fix if you work in a Gnome environment. See https://github.com/maiself/gnome-shell-extension-invert-color

Comment: so uh... why won't it work? i was working for me in 21.04 but some time after i upgraded to 21.10 i noticed it had stopped working.  no screen output issues, it just *does nothing*. it's late at night and I don't have time to figure out some stupid GNOME shell extension, i need dark *NOW*